# Export web page to pdf

Tags: asp.net

I am having a web page in which there is a canvas js chart. When I generated a pdf, the only canvas js chart do not displayed in the pdf.
How can I solve this problem?

Comment: how are you creating the js chart? is it svg?

Comment: In a jquery function.

Comment: $().canvasjschart();

Comment: We have used a different library todo javascript charts, the issue was related to the PDF not handling the js canvas correctly. We had to convert the javascript chart to png then convert the page to pdf

Comment: Okay. How will I do this? If you can suggest me important links on this.

Answer (score 0):

I previously had this issue, we ended up using: http://www.highcharts.com/ then exported to png -> http://www.highcharts.com/docs/export-module/export-module-overview.

After the svg-> png conversion we converted to PDF using standard libraries.

Comment: Gone through the site. What will write in c# to export to pdf?

Comment: well you have to make the graphs png/gif before you do the conversion to pdf. Since you already have a PDF conversion in place, use the same mechanism as you do originally, just make sure you convert to pdf after you convert the images.

Answer (score 0):

To export JS Chart into PDF, First you have to convert chart data into canvas image byte stream and then to PDF.
The following code will help you to convert JS Chart into PDF

**In Aspx Page**

```
<asp:HiddenField ID="hfImageData" runat="server" />
    <div id="dvTable">
       <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                                <div class="x_panel">
                                    <div class="x_title"> Your chart data comes here                                   <h2>                                            SLA                                   </h2>                                      

                                    </div>
                                    <div class="x_content">
                                        <canvas id="canvas000"></canvas>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
              </div>
         </div> 
</div>
  <asp:Button ID="btnExport" runat="server" Text="Export to PDF" CssClass="btn btn-primary" onclick="btnExport_Click" OnClientClick="return ConvertToImage(this)" />

 <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdn.rawgit.com/niklasvh/html2canvas/master/dist/html2canvas.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function ConvertToImage(btnExport) {

            html2canvas($("#dvTable")[0]).then(function (canvas) {

                var base64 = canvas.toDataURL();

                $("[id*=hfImageData]").val(base64);
                __doPostBack(btnExport.name, "");
            });
            return false;
        }
    </script>
```

**In Aspx.cs Page**

```
protected void btnExport_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string base64 = Request.Form[hfImageData.UniqueID].Split(',')[1];
        byte[] bytes = Convert.FromBase64String(base64);


        string fileName = "Chart.pdf";
        iTextSharp.text.Image image = iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance(bytes);
        using (MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            var pgSize = new iTextSharp.text.Rectangle(1600, 1000);
            Document document = new Document(pgSize, 88f, 88f, 10f, 10f);
            PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, memoryStream);
            document.Open();
            document.Add(image);
            document.Close();
            bytes = memoryStream.ToArray();
            memoryStream.Close();
        }
        Response.Clear();
        Response.Buffer = true;
        Response.Charset = "";
        Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
        Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
        Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + fileName);
        Response.BinaryWrite(bytes);
        Response.Flush();
        Response.End();
    }
```

whatever data present under div id "dvTable" will be converted to PDF when we click on Export

Comment: iTextSharp dll is required for this

Answer (score 0):

PhantomJS sounds like an option for you, take a look at the NReco wrapper for using it with .Net https://www.nrecosite.com/phantomjs_wrapper_net.aspx